# How to set scale and precision for MySQL float column in Phinx migration

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, phinx

I've got a column in a current MySQL table with definition `float(3,2)` and I need to expand it to be `float(4,2)`.  How do I do this with a Phinx (CakePHP) migration column specification?

Comment: This was addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39904183/cakephp-migrations-how-to-specify-scale-and-precision

Comment: FYI the `float(M, D)` syntax is deprecated and will be removed from a future version of MySQL, so you might think twice about designing your app with this in mind. Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html

Comment: @miken32: that only addresses decimal and numeric types, not float.

Bill Karwin:  Thanks for pointing that out!  If I were designing my app, I'd follow that advice.  But I'm modifying some really old legacy code, so don't have that choice.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The following appears to work, but is undocumented in both the Phinx and CakePHP documentation.  Use at your own risk, and test that the correct results are being generated.  The keys are `scale` for digits to right of decimal point and `precision` for maximum digits (width).

```php
public function up(): void
{
    $this->table('my_table')
        ->changeColumn('my_column', 'float', ['scale' => 2, 'precision' => 4])
        ->save();
}
```